# How can I do complex entity associations queries in doctrine 2? (virtual entity)

Tags: php, database-design, associations, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have a blog application.
The author can add multiple images to a post either by giving a link to a url of an existing image on the web, or upload a new image.

I want to be able to back track from an image (either uploaded or url) to all the posts that uses that image, and from a specific post to all the images in that post (for example - so I could delete images that are illegal and/or suspend the post that uses them until the author fixes the post).

However, I use different entities for an uploaded image vs a url image - an uploaded image has more data regarding the image than a url image.

This results in more complex code, as in each saving of an edited post I need to check which kind is the specific image (out of all the images in the post I need to run over), and than create or update its record, and assign to the relation field in the post entity.

So... assuming I have an `UploadedImage` and a `UrlImage` entities, I thought about having a `setImages` method in the `post` entity, which checks per each image it gets, if it's uploaded or url, and then calls either `setUploadedImages` or `setUrlImages`.

However, I will need some kind of a virtual `images` repository, to load images in the same way.

It sounds a bit complex, and I wondered:

1. How can I have a virtual doctrine entity (with its repository and all) ?
2. Is there a better design for it ?

Comment: Have you considered using [Inheritance Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)?

Comment: @Orbling in which way ? And how will it solve the "problem" of deciding what to do with each type ?

Comment: Well, by using Inheritance Mapping, you can have a superclass that represents both types, and then they can be handled together.  They can have the same methods and do different things depending on the subtype.

Comment: Doron is correct, this is exactly what Inheritence is about.  You have a base entity class (or mapped superclass) that provides all the functionality that's common to both types.  Both UrlImage and UploadedImage could then provide their own implementations of methods like `getUrl()`.  And you could have other methods that take an Image (doesn't matter which type) as a parameter, like 'flagAllPostsContainingImage($Image)`

Comment: For me personally it's interesting why Post entity should be somehow connected to UploadedImage ? It's only UrlImage it should care about

Comment: I also suggest to take look at Doctrine Embeddables http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's the documentation for what you are trying to do:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

It describes single table inheritance vs class table inheritance.
Your case is suited for the latter one, but consider migrating to the single table inheritance as well.

If (code) users of these images treat them the same regardless of their origin, added query complexity and database usage will not be worth the normalization.