# In Doctrine 2(.1) - Can I have a (virtual) repository for a MappedSuperclass entity?

Tags: inheritance, doctrine, repository, associations, doctrine-orm

I have a MappedSuperclass abstract class (`AbstractImage`), that 2 other entities inherit from it (`UrlImage` and `UploadImage`).

The Superclass has an association to another entity (`Post`), and I need a way to get and set instances of the `UrlImage` and `UploadImage` from and to the `Post` entity automatically ( = meaning that I'll have an `addImage` on the `Post` entity, which will know if the given entity is an `UploadImage` or `UrlImage` entity).

Likewise, since each entity has it's own `id` for records, I need a virtual repository that will have a `find` method, which will get the `id` and a `type` (`url` or `upload`) and call the `find` method on the appropriate repository (either `UploadImageRepository` or `UrlImageRepository`).

Getting a normal repository (like `UrlImageRepository`) is easy:

```
$em->getRepository('UrlImage');
```

but how can I do that on a `MappedSuperclass` ?

Here's some more information about the situation: [How can I do complex entity associations queries in doctrine 2? (virtual entity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716032/how-can-i-do-complex-entity-associations-queries-in-doctrine-2-virtual-entity)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but you can try making 3 repositories and making the `UploadImageRepository` and `UrlImageRepository` extend the third (base, virtual) repository.

Btw. a little advice on MappedSuperclasses... always make the abstract, otherwise you will run into all sorts of other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference. It's possible to load repository for AbstractImage, so `find` method would work for every inherited entity:

```
$imageRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('MyBundle:AbstractImage');
$urlImage = $imageRepository->find(1); //assuming record with id=1 is UrlImage entity
$uploadImage = $imageRepository->find(2); //assuming record with id=2 is UploadImage entity
```